# Bind Return key press to text box only while focused

Tags: wpf, xaml, key-bindings

I want to add a key binding to a `TextBox` so that when I press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, the appropriate command will fire, but I only want this to happen when the `TextBox` has focus on it.

The following code adds the binding, but it will fire whenever the <kbd>Return</kbd> key is pressed, no matter where the focus is in the window. Is it possible to restrict the key binding to only when the `TextBox` has focus?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchBoxNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour. If I put the following two `TextBoxes` in a `StackPanel`, give the keyboard focus to the second one and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the command is *not* fired.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchBoxNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to your `SearchCommand.CanExecute` so that it returns `false` when focus is not in `TextBox`. Unfortunately, `IsFocused`, `IsKeyboardFocused` and `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` are all read-only DP, you won't be able to bind to them from markup (XAML), even if you set the `Mode` to `OneWayToSource`. You can create your own control that derives from `TextBox` for this.

```
public class FocusAwareTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnIsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue != e.NewValue && e.NewValue != null)
        {
            HasFocus = (bool)e.NewValue;
        }

        base.OnIsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(e);
    }

    public bool HasFocus
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasFocusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasFocusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasFocusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(HasFocus),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(FocusAwareTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

You then bind the `HasFocus` DP to a new bool property in your ViewModel and add the check for this bool property in your `SearchCommand.CanExecute`.

Another solution would be to handle the `KeyDown` event instead and call the command from there. Note that you'll have to use a [Behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724708(v=expression.40).aspx) to keep the MVVM pattern.